# Customized bootstrap 4 table cell height differs between columns

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a customized Boostrap 4 style (to decrease padding, smaller font size and color tweaks) that has problems with table cells: the cell height differs between columns in the same table, which causes visual issues with borders, like so:

[image: Border errors]

Upon closer inspection we can see the s differ in height just slightly, that .6 difference is usually enough to show visual errors in most circumstances:

[image: cell height difference]

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sd917u6a/) with my customized stylesheet. Note that you might not see the border errors, sometimes it shows and sometimes it doesn't because of the small < 1 pixel difference.

Here are the changes from the default _variables.scss:

```
[glenn@centos7 scss]$ diff --side-by-side --suppress-common-lines ../../original/bootstrap-4.0.0/scss/_variables.scss _variables.scss 
$blue:    #007bff !default;                                   | $blue:    #337ab7 !default;
  "gray-dark":  $gray-800                                     | "gray-dark":  $gray-800,
  xl: 1200px                                                  | xl: 1200px,
                                                              > xl2: 1600px,
                                                              > xl3: 1800px
$line-height-sm:              1.5 !default;                | $line-height-sm:              1 !default;
$font-family-sans-serif:      -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFo | $font-family-sans-serif:      Arial, -apple-system, BlinkMacS
$font-size-base:              1rem !default; // Assumes the b | $font-size-base:              .8rem !default; // Assumes the 
$line-height-base:            1.5 !default;                | $line-height-base:            1.25 !default;
$table-cell-padding:          .75rem !default;                 | $table-cell-padding:          .5rem !default;
$input-btn-padding-y:         .375rem !default;            | $input-btn-padding-y:         .3rem !default;
$input-btn-padding-x:         .75rem !default;                | $input-btn-padding-x:         .6rem !default;
[glenn@centos7 scss]$
```

Thanks

Comment: Try rounding the value to get 44. [Read more here](https://gist.github.com/terkel/4373420)

Comment: Round which value? I'm not setting the td or tr height myself (and would prefer not to, I think this should just work as is?)